# Use type(print("1"))

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my first question,and I use Python 3.6.3

When I type the code:

```
type(print("1"))
```

It will get the output:

```
1
<class 'NoneType'>
```

I want to ask that why the code still print `1`,not just print  `<class 'NoneType'>`?

(Thanks,and sorry about my English ability :p)

Comment: `print` returns `None` **and** prints to the stdout. When you call `f(g(x))`, first the function `g` is called and then its output is fed to the function `f`.

Comment: Why shouldn't it print `1`? What do you think `print("1")` does?

Comment: The current answers miss a very important term in programming which is **side-effect**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science) . In this case the side effect of `print` is "writing to stdout".

Comment: I know that,but I think anything in **type()** will only print the type before :p.
And thank everyone's description!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use function(), you call the function. If you want to reference the function without calling it, drop the parentheses.

```
>>> type(print('1'))
1
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> type(print)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

When you use function as an argument to another function like so: `type(print("1"))`, python first executes the innermost function, in this case `print("1")`, then passes the return value as argument to the outer function, it's the same as:

```
result = print("1")
type(result)
```